# Read and get variable out of long object

Tags: php, arrays, string, object, cakephp

My only option to solve this problem is to read and get the variable out of the HTTP_REFERER. Here is the printed object I am trying to read and get a usable variable out of:

> App\Controller\EventsController Object ( [name] => Events [helpers]
>   => Array ( ) [request] => Cake\Http\ServerRequest Object ( [params] => Array ( [controller] => Events [action] => eventblock [pass] => Array
>   ( ) [plugin] => [_matchedRoute] => /:controller/:action/* [isAjax] =>
>   1 ) [data] => Array ( ) [query] => Array ( ) [cookies] => Array ( )
>   [_environment:protected] => Array ( [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_TMP] =>
>   /Applications/AMPPS/tmp [REDIRECT_REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
>   [REDIRECT_TMP] => /Applications/AMPPS/tmp [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
>   [TMP] => /Applications/AMPPS/tmp [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
>   [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive [HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache
>   [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => no-cache [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
>   [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest [HTTP_USER_AGENT] =>
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 [HTTP_REFERER]
>   => http://betpool/events/view/65506 [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] =>
>   de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 [PATH] =>
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => [SERVER_SOFTWARE]
>   => Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.0.16 mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/3.6 OpenSSL/1.0.1p [SERVER_NAME] => localhost [SERVER_ADDR] => ::1
>   [SERVER_PORT] => 80 [REMOTE_ADDR] => ::1 [DOCUMENT_ROOT] =>
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http [CONTEXT_PREFIX] =>
>   [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /Applications/AMPPS/www [SERVER_ADMIN] =>
>   admin@localhost [SCRIPT_FILENAME] =>
>   /Applications/AMPPS/www/betpool/online/betpool/webroot/index.php
>   [REMOTE_PORT] => 51901 [REDIRECT_URL] =>
>   /betpool/online/betpool/webroot/events/eventblock [GATEWAY_INTERFACE]
>   => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] =>
>   /betpool/online/betpool/events/eventblock [SCRIPT_NAME] =>
>   /betpool/online/betpool/webroot/index.php [PHP_SELF] =>
>   /betpool/online/betpool/webroot/index.php [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] =>
>   1504083056.053 [REQUEST_TIME] => 1504083056 [ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD] => GET [HTTPS] => ) [url] => events/eventblock [base] => /betpool/online/betpool [webroot] => /betpool/online/betpool/ [here]
>   => /betpool/online/betpool/events/eventblock [trustProxy] => [_input:protected] => [_detectorCache:protected] => Array ( [ajax] =>
>   1 [get] => 1 [head] => [options] => ) [stream:protected] =>
>   Zend\Diactoros\PhpInputStream Object (
>   [cache:Zend\Diactoros\PhpInputStream:private] =>
>   [reachedEof:Zend\Diactoros\PhpInputStream:private] =>
>   [resource:protected] => Resource id #87 [stream:protected] =>
>   php://input ) [uri:protected] => Zend\Diactoros\Uri Object (
>   [allowedSchemes:protected] => Array ( [http] => 80 [https] => 443 )
>   [scheme:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] => http
>   [userInfo:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] =>
>   [host:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] => localhost
>   [port:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] => [path:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private]
>   => /events/eventblock [query:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] => [fragment:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] =>
>   [uriString:Zend\Diactoros\Uri:private] => [base] =>
>   /betpool/online/betpool [webroot] => /betpool/online/betpool/ )
>   [session:protected] => Cake\Network\Session Object (
>   [_engine:protected] => [_started:protected] => [_lifetime:protected]
>   => 1440 [_isCLI:protected] => ) [attributes:protected] => Array ( ) [emulatedAttributes:protected] => Array ( [0] => session [1] =>
>   webroot [2] => base [3] => params ) [uploadedFiles:protected] => Array
>   ( ) [protocol:protected] => ....

Is it possible to get `http://betpool/events/view/65506` out of this code and if, is it possible to store this in a php var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mention which version of Cakephp you're using but Cakephp has a built-in mechanism for handling requests.

Follow the manual for more information:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::referer

```
$this->request->referer()
```

should return the string you're looking for.

Share some of your code for better guidance regarding the usage of this function.

Comment: THANK YOU for your help! This solved my problem perfectly